# I integrated admob in phonegap but admob displays 0 users

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I have one application on playstore and in my last version i integrated Admob into my app and it is based on Phonegap app and there are 970 users who are using latest version of app but still admob displays 0 users and in my app adds are displaying so what should i have to do ?? is there any way to check how many users are using it or its my admob ads not from that plugin provider so please help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. make sure you are using the right plugin. which admob plugin do you use? 2. set your own ad unit id when calling the plugin. can you paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your ad settings for application in google console. Maybe your select show ad only in the same location or for specific user.